# Make Xpath choose parts of an attribute

Tags: xpath, tablelayout

I have xml-documents with tables. Every table has an attribute hdsl-percent.

First of all, I'd like to know, what exactly that is . Never came across it. Google didn't yield any useful results.

Now, this attribute contains the widths of the table-columns in percentages, e.g. hsdl-percent="23.5 36.7 39.7".

Is there any way that I could get XPath to use these values for the widths of the table-columns? So 23.5% width for the first column and so on...

The problem is that each table is different, many of them with rowspans and colspans  and since I'm using Apache FOP and it doesn't support table-layout auto, my tables just have width="100%", no column-width specified and therefore some columns are wider than they should be.

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Maybe you could add an source input and expected output?

Comment: Which XSLT version are you using?

Comment: I am using version="1.0"

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I've got it. I managed to merge FOP with Saxon9he and am thus able to use XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0. I solved it like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@hsdl-percent,'\s+')">
<fo:table-column column-width="{concat(.,'%')}" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

**XPath 1.0** has rather limited string manipulation support, so splitting up is rather annoying. Use `substring($string, $start[, $length])`, `substring-before($string, $needle)` and `substring-after($string, $needle)`:

`substring(...)` will be fine if the strings are of fixed length (eg., no `4.2` occuring which is only three characters in length):

```
substring(//@hsdl-percent, 1, 4)
substring(//@hsdl-percent, 6, 4)
substring(//@hsdl-percent, 11, 4)
```

If length can change, you need to split at the space characters:

```
substring-before(//@hsdl-percent, ' ')
substring-before(substring-after(//@hsdl-percent, ' '), ' ')
substring-after(substring-after(//@hsdl-percent, ' '), ' ')
```

If you've got support for **XPath 2.0** (or better), use `tokenize($string, $needle)`:

```
tokenize(//@hsdl-percent, ' ') (: returns sequence of individual values :)
tokenize(//@hsdl-percent, ' ')[1]
tokenize(//@hsdl-percent, ' ')[2]
tokenize(//@hsdl-percent, ' ')[3]
```

Comment: Wow, thanx a lot! Will have to look at that a little while to understand it, though :D

Comment: Each of that lines is a single XPath expression to fetch the first/second/thirds field from that attribute.

Comment: Okay, another question: I never know in advance, how many values that attribute will have (or how many columns a table will have, respectively). It could be hdsl-percent="29.5 70.5" (two columns) or hsdl-percent="17 23 25 35" (4 columns) or whatever.Now wouldn't I need to say that the number of values in that attribute determines how many columns I have and the values themselves determine each column's length? So I would have to combine a for-each statement with those subtring-functions somehow, right? I basically need to write a highly flexible table-layout (w/o table-layout="auto",mind you).

Comment: There is no way to explicitly loop in XPath 1.0. I don't quite get what you need, too. To get the number of columns, you could use `string-length(translate("23.5 36.7 39.7", ' 1234567890.', ' ')) + 1` which removes all digits and the decimal point and counts the remaining string length (which is the number of spaces).

Comment: yeah, something like that might work. The problem is: I dont know how many columns there will be and I dont know how wide they will be. With the string-functions you showed me above, I would have to know in advance whether to use 2,3,4 or more of these, wouldnt I?

Comment: Yes you need to. You cannot do what you need in XPath 1.0, you will need to use it to select the data you need (eg. the attribute) and further process outside. XPath 2.0/XQuery would give you more options in here.